# Mysql query to transpose row into columns

Tags: mysql

I am writing a query to transpose the row into columns on basis of `id` column in the below shown table

```
Table1
id  value
80  3
80  
80  3
80  2
80  
80  2
81  6
81  
81  
81  
81  7
81  6
82  
82  
82  3
82  
82  
82  2
```

the output i require is as below

```
id  value1  value2  value3  value4  value5  value6
80  3       null    3       2       null    2
81  6       null    null    null    7       6
82  null    null    3       null    null    2
```

but the output what i am getting is as follows

```
id  value1  value2  value3  value4  value5  value6
80  3       3       3       3       3       3
81  6       6       6       6       6       6
82
```

the query i have is as follows

```
SELECT  
id,
IF(`id` = id , rate, rate) as value,
IF(`id` = id , rate, rate) as value,
IF(`id` = id , rate, rate) as value,
IF(`id` = id , rate, rate) as value,
IF(`id` = id , rate, rate) as value,
IF(`id` = id , rate, rate) as value
from
Table1
group by id;
```

kindly advice where am i going wrong and make necessary changes required to achieve this

Comment: Given that rows in RDBMS tables represent unordered sets, how do you propose to establish which one is value1?

Comment: i am trying to get it on basis of `id` and wanna transpose row in to columns

Comment: In which case I'm voting to close

Comment: though its an unordered set of data, the transposition of data from row to columns does the depends on the way you name the dynamic columns,
i believe while using pivoting this naming conventions does matters so much where as this can be a scenario sometime so was trying to get through

Comment: Unfortunately Sushil, you're not making any sense. Problems like the one you describe can be resolved - either within SQL or, better, application-level code - but not without the provision of a PRIMARY KEY, or some other way of uniquely identifying and ordering the data set.